# Creating a Windows installation media using a partitioned hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have a 1TB external hard drive that I have partitioned 10GB of (WINBOOT). I want to use that 10GB portion as installation media for Windows 10 with Boot Camp Assistant. However, when I go to make the boot drive, it automatically grabs the drive and will not let me select the partition.

[image: The drives my machine sees]

**If I unmount the main storage partition (Seagate Backup Plus) and create a boot drive with Boot Camp Assistant, will my files be safe?** I'm hoping Boot Camp Assistant use **only** the 10GB portion, and leave the other files untouched.